# javascript code to stop spam links in registration form

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, spam-prevention

we have a form for membership registration on our website with all fields validated via javascript _ the last two registrations have sent malware links  using the address field and a notes field _
Captcha is NOT a good option to prevent this _ so i have looked at regular expressions in javascript for banning 'http://' from these form fields but i'm confused by how to implement the code into the original form validation _
I'm wondering if anyone has a fragment of javascript code that will INVALIDATE writing 'http://' in our form _ or has a link to where i can find the javascript we need _
thanks

---

```
//Define global variables:
var fullNameReg = /^([a-zA-Z]+(-|\s*)[a-zA-Z]*)+$/;
var numberReg = /^([0-9]+(\s*|-)*[0-9]*)+$/;
var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
var dobReg = /^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/;

var bgColorErr = "#FFC36E";
var bgColor = "#FFE4BD";


$(document).ready(function(){

    document.getElementById("registrationForm").onsubmit = function onSubmit(form)
    {
        // Define logic variables:
        var formValid = true;
        var focusField = null;


        // Define form elememt variables:
        var fName = document.getElementById("fName");
        var dob = document.getElementById("dob");
        var address = document.getElementById("address");
        var telMob = document.getElementById("telMob");
        var telHome = document.getElementById("telHome");
        var email = document.getElementById("email");
        var consoleType = document.getElementById("consoleType");
        var wishList = document.getElementById("wishList");
        var gamerTag = document.getElementById("gamerTag");
        var tAndC = document.getElementById("tAndC");

        // Define form error span variables:
        var fNameErr = document.getElementById("fNameErr");
        var dobErr = document.getElementById("dobErr");
        var addressErr = document.getElementById("addressErr");
        var telMobErr = document.getElementById("telMobErr");
        var telHomeErr = document.getElementById("telHomeErr");
        var emailErr = document.getElementById("emailErr");
        var consoleTypeErr = document.getElementById("consoleTypeErr");
        var wishListErr = document.getElementById("wishListErr");
        var gamerTagErr = document.getElementById("gamerTagErr");
        var tAndCErr = document.getElementById("tAndCErr");



        // Full Name validation test:
        if (fName.value == "")
        {
            fNameErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColorErr;
            fNameErr.innerHTML = "You have not entered your name.<br /><br />";
            formValid = false;

            if (focusField === null)
            {
                focusField = fName;
            }
        }
        else if (!fullNameReg.test(fName.value))
        {

            fNameErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColorErr;
            fNameErr.innerHTML = "You have not entered your name correctly.<br /><br />";
            formValid = false;

            if (focusField === null)
            {
                focusField = fName;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            fNameErr.innerHTML = "";
            fNameErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
        }


        // Date of Birth validation test:
        if (dob.value == "")
        {
            dobErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColorErr;
            dobErr.innerHTML = "You have not entered your date of birth.<br /><br />";
            formValid = false;

            if (focusField === null)
            {
                focusField = dob;
            }
        }
        else if (!dobReg.test(dob.value))
        {
            dobErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColorErr;
            dobErr.innerHTML = "You have not entered your date of birth correctly.<br /><br />";
            formValid = false;

            if (focusField === null)
            {
                focusField = dob;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dobErr.innerHTML = "";
            dobErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
        }


        // Address validation test:
        if (address.value == "")
        {
            addressErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColorErr;
            addressErr.innerHTML = "You have not entered your address.<br /><br />";
            formValid = false;

            if (focusField === null)
            {
                focusField = address;
            }
        }
        else if (address.value.length < 5)
        {
            addressErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColorErr;
            addressErr.innerHTML = "You have not entered your address correctly.<br /><br />";
            formValid = false;

            if (focusField === null)
            {
                focusField = address;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            addressErr.innerHTML = "";
            addressErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
        }


        // Mobile Number validation test:
        if (telMob.value == "")
        {
            telMobErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColorErr;
            telMobErr.innerHTML = "You have not entered your mobile phone number.<br /><br />";
            formValid = false;

            if (focusField === null)
            {
                focusField = telMob;
            }
        }
        else if (telMob.value.length < 11 || !numberReg.test(telMob.value))
        {
            telMobErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColorErr;
            telMobErr.innerHTML = "You have not entered your mobile phone number correctly.<br /><br />";
            formValid = false;
            if (focusField === null)
            {
                focusField = telMob;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            telMobErr.innerHTML = "";
            telMobErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
        }


        // Home Number validation test:
        if (telHome.value != "" && (telHome.value.length < 9 || !numberReg.test(telHome.value)))
        {
            telHomeErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColorErr;
            telHomeErr.innerHTML = "You have not entered your home phone number correctly.<br /><br />";
            formValid = false;

            if (focusField === null)
            {
                focusField = telHome;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            telHomeErr.innerHTML = "";
            telHomeErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
        }

        // Email Address validation test:
        if (email.value == "")
        {
            emailErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColorErr;
            emailErr.innerHTML = "You have not entered your email address.<br /><br />";
            formValid = false;

            if (focusField === null)
            {
                focusField = email;
            }
        }
        else if (!emailReg.test(email.value))
        {
            emailErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColorErr;
            emailErr.innerHTML = "You have not entered your email address correctly.<br /><br />";
            formValid = false;

            if (focusField === null)
            {
                focusField = email;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            emailErr.innerHTML = "";
            emailErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
        }


        // Game Console Type validation test:
        if (consoleType.value == "")
        {
            consoleTypeErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColorErr;
            consoleTypeErr.innerHTML = "You have not selected your console type.<br /><br />";
            formValid = false;

            if (focusField === null)
            {
                focusField = consoleType;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            consoleTypeErr.innerHTML = "";
            consoleTypeErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
        }


        // Customer Wishlist validation test:
        if (wishList.value == "")
        {
            wishListErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColorErr;
            wishListErr.innerHTML = "You have not entered any games in your Wishlist.<br /><br />";
            formValid = false;

            if (focusField === null)
            {
                focusField = wishList;
            }
        }
        else if (wishList.value.length < 3)
        {
            wishListErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColorErr;
            wishListErr.innerHTML = "You have not entered at least one correct game in your Wishlist.<br /><br />";
            formValid = false;

            if (focusField === null)
            {
                focusField = wishList;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            wishListErr.innerHTML = "";
            wishListErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
        }


        // Customer Gamer Tag or Name validation test:
        if (gamerTag.value == "")
        {
            gamerTagErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColorErr;
            gamerTagErr.innerHTML = "You have not entered an online ID or your name.<br /><br />";
            formValid = false;

            if (focusField === null)
            {
                focusField = gamerTag;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            gamerTagErr.innerHTML = "";
            gamerTagErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
        }


        // Terms and Conditions acceptance test:
        if (!tAndC.checked)
        {
            tAndCErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColorErr;
            tAndCErr.innerHTML = "You have not ticket to confirm reading the terms and conditions.<br /><br />";
            formValid = false;

            if (focusField === null)
            {
                focusField = tAndC;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            tAndCErr.innerHTML = "";
            tAndCErr.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
        }


        // Focus on the first problem field.
        if (focusField != null)
        {
            focusField.focus();
        }

        // Return the validity of the form.     
        return formValid;       
    }

});
```

Comment: You do know that javascript is clientside right? If you don't check the credentials serverside, this whole check is kinda useless..

Comment: hi Ron _ thanks for your comment &of course you are totally correct _
but hopefully i can use the code below (so kindly created by Washington) to at least take away the 'clickability' of the links inside these malicious registrations_ which will at least prevent unsuspecting staff from investigating further _ perhaps unfortunately this will have to do for now _

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression should look like this:

```js
var inputText = "my adreess is city ... and spam http://somelink... and another www.link... 50";

var regexClearSites = /(?:http|www)\S+\s*/g;

document.write( 
  
  inputText.replace(regexClearSites, '')

);
```

Explaining the regex:

```
(?:http|www)       # any text starting with "http" or "www"
\S+\s*             # till the next space
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: WOW!! Thanks so much for taking the time to do this Washington
It will help a great deal! : )

Answer (score 0):

I think the [honeypot technique](https://solutionfactor.net/blog/2014/02/01/honeypot-technique-fast-easy-spam-prevention/) is a very elegant, simple anti-spam device - just hide a field with css and if it gets filled in you know it's a spambot doing it so trash the submission

Comment: thanks for your answer Lucas _ i have considered this option _ 
but these last two registrations have filled in the other required fields with different details which leads me to believe that it's a human being filling in the form which is why i don't think Captcha will work either _
i really need the javascript to recognise a link being posted and then refuse to send the form _ 
but thanks again for your answer : )